# How to import javascript object from node_modules into Vue with Laravel and webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, import, node-modules

When I try to import an object into from my node_modules into my vue component with webpack using exports-loader I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/qrcodejs/qrcode.js (./node_modules/exports-loader/dist/cjs.js?QRCode!./node_modules/qrcodejs/qrcode.js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/exports-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Exports Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options misses the property 'exports'. Should be:
   non-empty string | object { name, syntax?, alias? } | [non-empty string | object { name, syntax?, alias? }, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item)
```

I use vue with Laravel and my components looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import QRCode from 'exports-loader?QRCode!qrcodejs/qrcode';

    export default {
         props: [
            'order',
        ],

        methods: {
            createQR(){
                new QRCode("output", {
                    text: this.order,
                    width: 500,
                    height: 500,
                    colorDark: "#188710",
                    colorLight: "#ffffff"
                });
            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

This worked just fine in a different javascript project I created (but without Vue and Laravel)
I defined the following rule inside the index.js file from qrcodejs in order to import the qrcode:

```
// Export namespace
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /qrcode/, loader: 'exports-loader?QRCode' }
        ]
    }
}
```

So what does my error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by by uninstalling exports-loader and installing exports-loader version 0.7.0.

```
npm install exports-loader@0.7.0
```